# Sneat theme Local script not working with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use `Sneat` theme with basic HTML and bootstrap 5. I am using it in react application, not using react template because I just want basic HTML and CSS in my application for the theme. But while importing the `.js` file in my app index.html, I am getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.

Here is the HTML file for my React app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  lang="en"
  class="light-style layout-menu-fixed"
  dir="ltr"
  data-theme="theme-default"
  data-assets-path="./assets/"
  data-template="vertical-menu-template-free"
>
  <head>
    <!-- Helpers -->
    <script src="./assets/vendor/js/helpers.js"></script> { // error}
    <script src="./assets/js/config.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="./assets/vendor/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>  { // error}
  <script src="./assets/vendor/libs/popper/popper.js"></script> { // error}
  <script src="./assets/vendor/js/bootstrap.js"></script> { // error}
  <script src="./assets/vendor/libs/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script> { // error}

  <script src="./assets/vendor/js/menu.js"></script> { // error}
  <!-- endbuild -->

 
</body>

</html>
```

Helpers.js file - one of which i am getting error for

```
(function(e, a) { for(var i in a) e[i] = a[i]; }(window, /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "./js/helpers.js");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./js/helpers.js":
/*!***********************!*\
  !*** ./js/helpers.js ***!
  \***********************/
/*! exports provided: Helpers */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {


-- Now some Wbepack complied code in file
```

I have tried pasting raw code for the webpack minified code , and various other thing. I know its tricky but still if someone could help.

Error on line, when I click on the error.
[Error on Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYp2s.png)

Response:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvZda.png)

This is the `https://demos.themeselection.com/sneat-bootstrap-html-admin-template/html/vertical-menu-template/`, that i am trying to just use html of a particular component of.

Comment: There is no `<` in the helper.js code? Maybe it's not loading correctly and the browser is trying to parse an 404 error page?

Comment: Yes thats would be a case as i can see . Any idea how can i make it work, because as i see in this theme file , their html working without any error , but same not working on my react App. I am stuck like what now should i do as their documentation is not very supportive in this case.

Comment: I would also recommend not mixing React and jQuery

Comment: @RITIKSINGH: Open your browser's debugging tools and observe the network tab when loading the page.  For any given JavaScript resource which is failing to load, what is the request being made to the server?  What is the server's response?  Does the URL of that request match what you expect?

Comment: Yeah, I looked on that , on that request their is no outside call, but the response is the same helper.js code which is present in public folder.

Comment: @RITIKSINGH: So the request for a JavaScript file is responding with JavaScript code, but it's producing the error *"Unexpected token '<'"*?  Which specific line of code is the error message referring to?

Comment: @David, i have attached both the things. Please have a look. And this is not for just this file but for menu.js, helper.js (I mean all public folder js file)

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to use bootstrap (HTML/CSS) version in React template. In this case, I suggest using react version of the same product: [Sneat MUI React Admin Template](https://themeselection.com/item/sneat-mui-react-nextjs-admin-template/). It is already integrated with React using Material UI. Thus, you can directly use the product for your project without any hassle.

Still, if you want to integrate HTML/CSS/JS code from HTML template to react template (which I don't recommend), you have to carefully include required files and convert the HTML, CSS & JS code to react compatible code.